# Deploy Vue + Go as single binary to Heroku

Tags: heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have merged my seperate frontend and backend repo to a single one. My gitlab-ci pipeline worked perfectly for the seperate projects but I can not get it to work as a single project.

The pipeline for the single backend project:

```
...

staging:
  image: ruby
  stage: deployment
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_STAGING --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  environment:
    name: Staging
  only:
    - staging
```

The pipeline for the single frontend project:

```
...

build site:
  image: node
  stage: build
  script:
    - yarn install --progress=false
    - yarn build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist

staging:
  image: ruby
  stage: deployment
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$$HEROKU_APP_STAGING --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  environment:
    name: Staging
  only:
    - staging
```

I then decided to merge both projects together. The project structure looks like this:

```
Project
 |
 +-- backend
 |    
 +-- frontend
 |  |  
 |  +-- dist
 |  |  
 |  +-- package.json
 |    
 +-- Procfile
 |    
 +-- .gitlab-ci.yml
```

The Go backend serves the Vue frontend on a static route. So I need to build the frontend before the backend and then reference the generated dist directory in my backend build.

This is the Procfile:

```
web: backend
```

This is my current state of my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
...

build frontend:
  image: node
  stage: frontend
  script:
    - cd frontend
    - yarn install --progress=false
    - yarn build
  artifacts:
    name: "frontend"
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - frontend/dist

build backend:
  image: golang
  stage: backend
  script:
    - cd backend
    - go build
    - ls -la
  artifacts:
    name: "backend"
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - backend/backend

staging:
  image: ruby
  stage: deployment
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl  --skip_cleanup --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_STAGING --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  environment:
    name: Staging
  only:
    - staging
```

This version of the pipeline fails on the deployment with following error:

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/go.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
deploy failed
```

There is no further information to check what exactly has been uploaded. To my understanding it should only be the binary which should not fail.

What am I doing wrong or what are my missunderstandings?

EDIT:
Updated staging part:

```
staging:
  image: ruby
  stage: deployment
  script:
    - ./detect backend
    - cd backend
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - ls -la ../frontend/dist
    - ls -la
    - dpl --skip_cleanup --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_STAGING --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    - ls -la
```

Returns:

```
$ ./detect backend
Go

$ ls -la
total 30896
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root     4096 Sep 21 11:39 .
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root     4096 Sep 21 11:03 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     4096 Sep 18 15:03 controllers
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     1306 Sep 21 10:11 go.mod
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    56556 Sep 21 10:11 go.sum
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root      251 Sep 18 13:14 main.go
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31527936 Sep 21 11:38 backend
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     4096 Sep 18 13:14 middleware
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root     4096 Sep 18 13:14 model

...
       Detected the following main packages to install:
            backend
       
-----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku backend 
...

github.com/jackc/pgx/v4
github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/stdlib
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
 !     Push failed
deploy failed
```

Comment: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/main/bin/detect this `detect` script is run to check whether your project is compatible with the heroku-buildpack-go.

Comment: Hi Tin, I checked out the script you've referenced. As you can see in my edit it is compativle with heroku-buildpack. Any idea why the push is getting rejected now?